# Is complexity O(log(n) + log(n/2) + log(n/4) + log(n/8) + ... + log(2)) = O(log(n))?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

As homework, I was asked to write an algorithm in O(log(n)) and I could calculate the complexity of the one I wrote as O(log(n) + log(n/2) + log(n/4) + log(n/8) + ... + log(2)).

I think it's rather O(n) since it's roughly log(n)*O(log(n)) = O(n). But I was not sure about it. I know homework questions are not welcome here, but  I really don't know another way to find out what complexity it is. Googling didn't help me.

To specify: n in N and n = pow(2, c), c in N

Comment: `(log n)^2` is not at all like `n`.

Answer (score 10):

No, it's not O(log n). It is O((log n)<sup>2</sup>).

```
O(log(n) + log(n/2) + log(n/4) + log(n/8) + ... + log(2))
= O(log(n * n/2 * n/4 * n/8 * ... * 2))                    using log multiplication rule
= O(log(n * n * n * ... * n / 2 / 4 / 8 / ... / n))
= O(log(nlog n / 2 / 4 / 8 / ... / n))
= O(log(nlog n / (1 * 2 * 4 * 8 * ... * n/4 * n/2 * n))
= O(log(nlog n / ((1 * n) * (2 * n/2) * (4 * n/4) * ...)    group first and last terms
= O(log(nlog n / (n * n * n * ...))                         since we grouped terms,
= O(log(nlog n / n(log n)/2)                                      we halved the number of terms
= O(log(nlog n) - log(n(log n)/2))                             log division rule
= O(log n.log n) - ((log n)/2).log n)                      log power rule * 2
= O(log n.log n) - (log n.log n)/2)
= O(log n.log n)/2)
= O((log n)2/2)
= O((log n)2)                                              big-O doesn't care about constants
```

Comment: All the equalities are exact but one where (n * n * n * ...) is in fact equal to (n<sup>(log n - 1)/2</sup>) if `log n` is odd or (n<sup>(log n)/2</sup> / n) if log n is even.

Answer (score 2):

Start with some basic arithmetic:

```
O(log n/2) = O( (log n) + log(1/2))
```

The constant can be ignored.  Hence:

```
O(log n / 2) = O(log n)
```

So, you are adding a bunch of things that are O(log n).  How many?  Well, about log(n) worth.  So, that means that the algorithm is:

```
O( (log n)^2)
```

Comment: Ok so my thought `it's roughly log(n)*O(log(n)) = O(n)` was right. I guess I need to find another algorithm then. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `O(log n/2) = O( (log n) - (log 2))`? Also, the subtracted terms aren't constant - log 2, log 4, log 8, ... log n scales i.t.o. n.

Comment: You can't neglect an infinite number of (growing) constant terms (ie not constant actually... The terms you're neglecting actually also sum up to O((log(n))^2) so it's just lucky for you to get the right answer although neglecting them...

Comment: @gdelab . . . For any constant, O(n / C) = O(n).  That is not "luck" that is how complexity is defined.  The key is the number of terms, not the complexity of each one.

Comment: Yes, but here, if you do the computations properly, you end up with `log(n)*log(n)+(log(1/2)+log(1/4)+...+log(1/n))`. The second part is not a constant, nor can it be trivially neglected, as you suggest: it is a sum with `Omega(log(n))` terms, some of them of size `Omega(log(n))`. Their sum is actually of size `Theta((log(n))^2)`. You can't neglect all the elements in that sum one by one as you're doing ! See @Dukeling 's answer for better computations (although still not 100% rigorous either, using '...' instead of the sum / multiplication symbols)